# Non-Analytic extrapolation

Tags: robust, extreme-value, control-chart

I have some samples of a stable real-world process.  Its is polymodal, and does not cleanly fit any of the "textbook" analytic distributions.  I need to make very accurate estimates of the maximum value for a number of samples that is much larger than what I have.

Two things that I thought of and have shown not to work:

1. Compute iqr, multiply it by 4, and add it to the median.  This is a robust-statistic analog of offsetting a control limit so to get a Cpk of 1.33 using mean and standard deviation for a normal distribution.  This sets limits way too wide.
2. Choose the maximum and minimum of the current distribution.  This under-estimates the extremal value.

UPDATE:

I tried and had semi-consistent results when I fit the data to a Gaussian Mixture Model. I used the AIC indicated number of parameters. In inverse CDF domain, probit, the Gaussian is a line, so I think this is just the equivalent of using 3 piecewise smooth lines (with fillets) to interpolate in the domain. However, it still seems not strong enough. It seems un-rigorous. I could make a mixture of t-distributions, or other fits, if I believed that they made a good basis for the underlying systems. The wider tails might be useful for real-world data.

Comment: The "extrapolation" in the title says it all: *you are making up the answer arbitrarily* when you estimate extreme values from smaller datasets. All such estimates rely on assumptions about the shape of the tail; there is no getting around that. Methods like those you have discussed are just ways of hiding this fact, which explains why they do not work. Your only hope is to learn something about the tails either from theory or from other related datasets and incorporate that knowledge in your modeling.

Comment: It was measurements from a stationary physical process.  This means that the measurements were based on the larger system, that they can tell me some things about it, and that the system being described has constrained and consistent behavior. Just like flood (or other actuarial) prediction, there are ways this problem is engaged that are as solid as they can be, and were likely better than my younger self trying to invent them.

Comment: That's fair--but what you're saying is that this is a physics problem before it's a statistical problem.  You need the underlying physical theory to suggest a model before statistical methods can be of any help.

Comment: Boy I wish that had been available. Would’ve been really nice.

Comment: Almost by definition, physical processes are amenable to physical modeling and reasoning!

Comment: The upstream production process had 15,000 distinct and complex upstream steps.  Just because it is possible in theory and with enough money doesn't make it reasonable or economical.  :)

Comment: Very often, even basic physical reasoning and approximations provide insight into the likely nature of a relationship.  That's certainly more information than a purely abstract formulation of the problem provides.

Comment: And the road from the abstract formulation to the basic physical reasoning and approximations is an art, and the skilled practitioner there can make a world of difference.  Folks with those capabilities, not-online, can be challenging to find.  Impo, CV is a place that has a relatively higher density of them than most other places.  ;)  I can read the papers and textbooks, but only here can I learn from the highly competent (like you, and several others) who have walked those non-textbook roads.

Comment: Thank you for the kind remarks.  My motivation in this case arises from your focus on tails.  By their very nature they are difficult to model and characterize, because they are represented by a tiny subset of the data.  I am therefore convinced that one of the best approaches to tail characterization brings in whatever information you can glean about the likely shape of the tail, for otherwise you are doomed to a high degree of uncertainty.  Even here on CV many people uncritically recommend applying, say, a KDE, which *imposes* the tail behavior of the kernel: that's hardly insightful!